# Unix copy command that has a progress bar, but not as heavy as rsync

Tags: rsync, copy, cp

I need to copy lots of files. Usually I use rsync because I pass it the `-aP` options and I can see (a) how many files are left to process and (b) how much of each individual file is copied.

However rsync also does lots of things with checksums to verify that a file was copied. However I don't really need that now. But normal `cp` doesn't include the above mentioned count of files left, which is very helpful.

Is there anything like `cp` that includes progress of how many files left, but isn't as heavy as `rsync`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could run rsync with the -W switch, which will disable the checksums.

Answer (score 6):

So is this a suitable alias for your suggestions?

```
cp_p() {
    rsync -WavP $1 $2
}
```

-W -do not use delta transfer algorithm
-a archive mode
-v verbose
-P show progress bar and retain partial files

another alternative i found at some [places](http://jkeating.livejournal.com/64342.html). requires pv (pipeviewer) package though.

```
cp_pv() {
    pv -per $1 > $2
}
```

-p show progress
-e show eta
-r show rate
-n show numeric output

/edit
I have now tested the above aliases and can confirm they work. There were some typos before

Comment: This seems to only support copying one file into a named file rather than a directory. What if I want to copy multiple files? Or a directory?

Comment: Well these are just aliases, so you can experiment with the actual raw commands inside to see what works for you. I'm sure rsync supports directories and other path designations. You can easily customize the aliases to make it work for your specific situation. Do share if you get it working. IIRC I have used it with directories before without a problem.

Answer (score 3):

you could just slap the -v option on the cp cmd or use scp to the localhost

Comment: the -v is a good start, and it's quite helpful, but I'd like more info on exactly how many files are left / have been copied / etc

Comment: Then you want Stefan Wolff's solution.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at pipeviewer/pv:

http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml

Example for copy:

http://blog.amit-agarwal.co.in/2010/11/11/function-copy-files-progress-bar-pv-pipe-viewer/

Answer (score 1):

It's overkill with the encryption overhead, but you can use `scp` locally:

```
scp <file-from> <file-to>
```

It will display progress while copying.

Comment: Atleast on OSX, `scp` doesn't show any progress bar by default as it uses `cp` under the hood when local files are involved.

Answer (score 1):

`gcp` is the nice tool. Here you have the [PyPI package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gcp), but this also can be found in distro package (for example in [debian](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/main/gcp)/[ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcp) `apt-get install gcp` do the job).

There is also a nice [tutorial article about gcp](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/03/gcp-command-line-file-copy-ubuntu-linux/).

```
$ gcp -r Solaar/ solaar2

Copying 7.53 MiB 100% |#############################| 134.92 M/s Time: 00:00:00
```